# added vline does not appear on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot

```
 dat = data.frame(x = c(55,56) , y = c(200,300))
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(x, ordered = TRUE), y =y)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept =  55, linetype = "solid"   ), color = "red")
```

The vertical line is not appearing. How can I make it appear over the bars? Thank you.

Comment: You can put the line at `1` to get a line over the first category on the categorical x axis.  Otherwise leave `x` as numeric for the bars and it will work as you have it.

Comment: Unless you want a legend that says linetype and shows the red line then you should also remove the aes() wrapper in your call to geom_vline().